# Qt static build - impossible size

Tags: c++, qt, static-linking, shared-libraries

I am quite new to Qt programming, and i tried long to understand how linking the libraries work. I need to distribute a **small program** - 1000 lines or so - that i developed to a few people.
**I built statically Qt** because **I need a static build**, and now my programs size increased drammatically.
I only use Qpushbuttons, Qlinedits, Qlabels, and a few more things and I ended up with a compiled program of over **160Mb, while just a few MB would be reasonable**.
I assume it included unwanted libraries and classes (only explanation).
How can I keep the size something acceptable with a static build?

I'm running linux 64bit and need to compile as such and for it.

thanks

Comment: How do you know that for **all** the platform abstraction code which Qt provides, a few MB would be reasonable?

Comment: your few ui stuff is just the tip of the iceberg, and you have limited control over what you can do. But you can reduce by : stripping debugging information if any; Use Qt5 rather than qt4. it has a better decoupling. if you are already using qt5 with zero debuggin symbols, that's the best you can get.

Comment: @Angew, well, any small program isn't more than a few MB in size I don't know how mine should be different. How many times have you seen a small gui program of more a few MB? (could be a basic text editor or such

Comment: I believe most GUI programs link GUI libraries dynamically, so that's hardly a useful comparison. The best you can do, in addition to what UmNyobe says, is search your link line for any spurious `--whole-archive` options, and play around with other linker options (such as `-s` and `-S`).

Comment: FWIW, how big are the static Qt libraries you link against?

Comment: Hey @Angew Thousands of files of at maximum 15kb each, and each stands for an include, total of several Gbs. Allright,  including some brings several other with it, but still....
(BTW: fwiw?  I had to Google that.)
You said generally programs are dynamic linked,  and that in part is true, but how do they work on computers that don't have the libraries? They gotta be statically linked for most dependencies, yet they aren't heavy as my stuff.  How come? What is it that I don't know?

Comment: @user3887576 I was asking about the size of the static libraries themselves - `.a` files in your case. And I would assume that on platforms where the dynamic libraries are not available, the program will just ship them with itself.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you are doing a project build in debug mode.  I propose to build application in the release mode.  The size of the output file will decrease dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, you need to build qt in release mode. I have been building qt for a couple of years. The best and simplest method I've done is (both Linux and Windows):

1. Install Qt sources. (last available)
2. Install Python 2.7.X to build QML (last available)
3. Open terminal and execute configure command in src directory:

**LINUX:**
`./configure -prefix "/somePath/Qt511Static" -static -release -opensource -confirm-license -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -fontconfig -qt-xcb -opengl desktop -sql-sqlite -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine`

**WINDOWS:**
`configure -prefix "/somePath/Qt511Static" -static -static-runtime -release -opensource -confirm-license -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -sql-sqlite -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine`

5. Build: `make -k -jN` (Linux) or `mingw32-make -k -jN` (Windows)
6. Install: `make -k install` (Linux) or `mingw32-make -k -jN` (Windows)
7. Set the kit in Qt Creator.
   Goto *Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Qt Versions* and search your newly installed qmake executable. **Apply changes**. Then goto *Kits* and create a new kit and set on it the newly qt version.

**NOTE:** Use flag `-release` to make smaller apps (~20 MB).

**NOTE:** Use flag `-jN` to build faster (using multiples jobs). Replace `N` with the number of cores of your processors.