# qt static build gives linking error

Tags: qt, static-linking

I compiled [Qt source with static build](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW) and now done everything with this instruction but when I am trying to compile my project I get the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
...
```

As I understood it missing libraries.
How can I add libraries in that project or on static kit?
Or maybe there is different problem?

Comment: You may have used `gcc` instead of `g++`?

Comment: no I use g++ 'qmake.exe my_project.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=release" '. this is command from qt creator

Comment: See this, may help you to successfully compile qt statically:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51233988/7336312